# Recursive call on the worksheet change in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created the workbook with multiple sheet, i am trying to use WorkSheet_Change on `Sheet1`, i.e. something change on sheet1 is getting copied to sheet2. Similarly if anything change to `Sheet2` i want to make similiar change on `Sheet1` as well.

On doing so there is recursive call on both sheet please let me know how i can avoid this.

Comment: Can you post the *relevant* code?

Comment: @JMax: You still cared enough to answer! You're a better man than I.

Comment: @Jean-François: that was an easy one. Besides, i'm sure NewDev will eventually understand how Stackoverflow works and accept the answers that were previously given to him

Comment: Still i have no solution therefore i have not checked any answer yet

Comment: in one worksheet i have Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  
    Call FilterToShowAsterisk("Robin")
    Call RobinCopyFilter("Robin")
 

    
End Sub

Comment: In second worksheet i have Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      End Sub

Comment: @NewDev: there are 5 older questions you never accepted.

Comment: Maybe the answers to his other questions suck too?

Answer (score 9):

you should **disable events** when calling your macro:

```
Sub Donot_Fire_Events()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ' Coding to skip these events
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: As i have not done coding on the Module level i Cannot declare aglobal vairiable, Code is written in the Microsoft Excel object Sheets. Please help how can I apply this in code

Comment: You comment doesn't apply to my solution. You should disable event at the beginning of your procedure and re-enable them at the end. If you want more help, post the code as El Ronnoco suggested in his/her comment.

Comment: This is the correct answer -- there are no global variables used here and this is not at the module level.  At the top of your function that's getting called recursively you tell Excel to stop firing events, at the bottom (before you exit -- and again in your error handler if they're not the same block of code) you turn events back on.

Answer (score 1):

Put a new global variable in a Module and call it `bAutoUpdating As Boolean` for example.

When the _Change code runs it should set this to `true`. Also any change routine should **not** fire if this is `true`. At the end of each _Change routine set back to `bAutoUpdating = false`

Comment: As i have not done coding on the Module level i Cannot declare aglobal vairiable, Code is written in the Microsoft Excel object Sheets.

Comment: @NewDev - You can create a new Module - and the existing code within your Sheets will be able to access the variable in it - provided it is declared `Public`