# vba crashes when copying contents of a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set up an Excel spreadsheet to function like a database (the user does not have MS Access,  etc.) I have a second sheet set up as a pivot table to analyse the data records.

To ensure the users spell names consistently, I have set up a lookup column with names that have been used before.  If an unrecognised name is detected, I am using data validation on the lookup list to ask the user to confirm the spelling or indicate that it is a new name to add to the system.

I then want the code to copy the name to the lookup column and change the status of another column which controls which columns the user is able to fill in. This bit is crashing the code.

I have pasted the sub below with the offending bit set as comments.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect


    Dim row As Integer
    Dim emptyrow As Integer
    Dim prevrow As Integer

    For emptyrow = 3 To 20000

        If ActiveSheet.Cells(emptyrow, 1).Text = "" Then
            row = emptyrow - 1
            prevrow = row - 1

            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(emptyrow, 2), Cells(emptyrow, 26)).Locked = True

            If row > 2 Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Locked = False
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, 2), Cells(row, 26)).Locked = True
            End If

            If prevrow > 2 Then ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(prevrow, 1), Cells(prevrow, 26)).Locked = True

      '      If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 4).Text = "Y" Then
      '          ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Locked = False
      '          ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Text = "Add/update person"
      '          ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 29).Locked = False
      '          ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 29).Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 3).Text
      '      End If

            If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Text = "Add/update person" Then
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, 17), Cells(row, 26)).Locked = True
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, 2), Cells(row, 16)).Locked = False
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 23).Locked = False
                ActiveSheet.Cells(emptyrow, 1).Locked = False
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Text = "Signposting" Then
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, 2), Cells(row, 26)).Locked = True
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, 2), Cells(row, 5)).Locked = False
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, 17), Cells(row, 18)).Locked = False
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 23).Locked = False
                ActiveSheet.Cells(emptyrow, 1).Locked = False
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Text = "Referral" Then
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, 2), Cells(row, 26)).Locked = True
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, 2), Cells(row, 5)).Locked = False
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, 19), Cells(row, 20)).Locked = False
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 23).Locked = False
                ActiveSheet.Cells(emptyrow, 1).Locked = False
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Text = "Training" Then
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, 2), Cells(row, 26)).Locked = True
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, 2), Cells(row, 5)).Locked = False
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(row, 21), Cells(row, 23)).Locked = False
                ActiveSheet.Cells(emptyrow, 1).Locked = False
            End If

            ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 23).Locked = False
            ActiveSheet.Cells(emptyrow, 1).Locked = False

            emptyrow = 20000

        End If

    Next emptyrow

    ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this an Excel crash or just a Run Time Error?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is using .Text to set a value to a cell.  The text property returns or sets the text for an object. You can check if a cell contains certain text such as "Y" but you cannot add text to a cell the way you have it set up.
I think this should work:

```
If ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 4) = "Y" Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 1).Locked = False
            ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 1) = "Add/update person"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 29).Locked = False
            ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 29) = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 3)
        End If

If ActiveSheet.Cells(Row,4).Text = "Y" Then
```

should work as well but seems redundant.

Comment: This is also causing it to crash.  I have tried to narrow it down by commenting out the rows and enabling them one at a time.  It will crash whenever I try to change the value of a cell, so either the 3rd or 5th line in the code above causes a crash.

Comment: I tried it with the above code pasted in.  I'm not exactly sure what your worksheet looks like but I tried to make on where I added some names in column C and Y in column D.  Everything seems to work.  I also protected the worksheet first before beginning.  Is there anything else that needs to be on the sheet?

Comment: Sounds like something else on the worksheet might be interfering with it.  You can download the file here http://headwaycs.co.uk/?attachment_id=13209

Comment: In the end I re-worked the sheet to leave out the bit that was causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are getting the error "Unable to set the text value of the range class". This is because the text property is read only, you should use the value property instead.

```
  '          ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 29).Locked = False
  '          ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 29).value= ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 3).Text
```

Comment: I have had a number of error messages during the day including "unable to set text value..."  I have also tried various combinations of .value  .text etc.  Using this code I get the message "out of stack space"

Comment: hm, well the only problem I see with the commented section is the text/value issue. If you update that and it still doesn't work then add some more details and maybe someone can help

Comment: @Rossi in order to prevent invalid assignment errors use `Option Explicit On`, in order to prevent infinite recursion inside the `Worksheet_Change` implement a guard as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911880/recursive-call-on-the-worksheet-change-in-vba